# Creating Universal (Or Just For PC) Windows Apps For The App Store C#

Tags: c#, windows, windows-store-apps

I wanted to start creating Windows Applications for the winodws app store, Seems like a fun area to play around with since im getting tired of all the management softwares that i am creating at the moment for schools and what not.

So my question is, How do I start with creating Windows Apps for the App Store.
Do I keep using C#?
What templates do I choose in Visual Studio when starting the project.
Is it easy to distribute to the windows app store?

Im completly new to Windows App development for the app store and I tried looking online for tips but all I could find was places where you coudl manage your apps etc, nothing about how to get started.

Comment: Buy a book, watch channel on youtube. Then think of some project and start working on it. In you don't know how to do it google it. For specific questions come here. Please alco check [mcve] and [ask] sections of this site.

Comment: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/getstarted

Comment: Microsoft virtual Academy https://mva.microsoft.com/en-US/training-courses/developing-universal-windows-apps-with-c-and-xaml-8363